# I am trying to embed JW player in my website. I get the error 'Video not found or access denied' when I try to play the video

Tags: html, jwplayer

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-    strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>SWFObject dynamic embed - step 1</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
     <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject/swfobject.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>  

  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="flashContent">
      <p>Alternative content</p>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var flashvars = { file:'/video.flv'};
    var params = { allowfullscreen:'true', allowscriptaccess:'always' };
    var attributes = { id:'player1', name:'player1' };

    swfobject.embedSWF('player1.swf','flashContent','480','270','9.0.115','false', flashvars, params, attributes, flashLoaded);

function flashLoaded(e) {
 // e.ref is a reference to the Flash object. We'll pass it to jwplayer() so the API knows where the player is.

 // Add event listeners
 jwplayer(e.ref).onReady(function() { alert('Player is ready'); e.ref.play();e.ref.seek(10); });
 jwplayer(e.ref).onPlay(function() { e.ref.play();});
 jwplayer(e.ref).onStop(function() { e.ref.stop();});
 jwplayer(e.ref).onVolume(function() { e.ref.seek(100);});
 // Interact with the player
 }

 </script>

 </body>
</html>
```

'video.flv' is in the same directory as the html file

Comment: this is not the case if the format is .mov. It only happens with .flv format. Is there a workaround for this?
Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: try removing the slash from `file:'/video.flv'` because that's usually used for absolute URLs, which means the video file must be in the web root of your site, which isn't necessarily where the HTML file is located.

Answer (score 0):

try to put full path
for example:

> var flashvars = { file:'http://yourwebsite.com/video.flv'};